# Fusion Chart with ajax in YII

Tags: php, fusioncharts, yii-extensions, yii

I have use fusion chart extension in my Yii application. I am using an ajax submit to create various graphs. It renders, but when i try to filter it with ajax, i get the same output.

This is my code in the view:

```
<?php 
$this->renderPartial('_search'); ?>
<p id="ChartArea" style="text-align:center;">
<?php 
$this->renderPartial('_chart',array('cchart'=>'mychart', 
'chartType'=>'Line','chartName'=>'callTrend','data'=>array('')));?>
```

In _search.php:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'calltrend-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
        'htmlOptions'=>array('onsubmit'=>"return false;"),
    ));
echo CHtml::hiddenField('chartType','Line');
echo CHtml::hiddenField('chartName','callTrend');
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".CHtml::Label('From:','from_date',
    array('style'=>'display:inline;clear:both;'))."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
        'attribute'=>'from_date',
        'name'=>'from_date',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'input-small','style'=>'margin-top:9px;'),
        'options'=>array(
            'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
            'altField' => '#self_pointing_id',
            'altFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
            'changeYear'=>'true',
            'changeMonth'=>'true',
        ),
    ));
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".CHtml::Label('To:','to_date',array('style'=>'display: 
inline;clear:both;'))."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
        'attribute'=>'to_date',
        'name'=>'to_date',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'input-small','style'=>'margin-top:9px;'),
        'options'=>array(
            'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
            'altField' => '#self_pointing_id',
            'altFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
            'changeYear'=>'true',
            'changeMonth'=>'true',),
    ));
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".CHtml::Label('Project:','project',array('style'=>' 
display:inline;clear:both;'))."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo CHtml::dropDownList('project','',CHtml::listData(Project::model()->findAll()
        ,'id','name'),array('empty' => '--- Choose---','class'=>'inputmedium','style'=>'
clear:both;margin-top:9px;'));
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".CHtml::submitButton(Yii::t('app',
        'Generate'),array('class'=>'btn btn-primary','style'=>'clear:both;'));
echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Generate',
    CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('site/chart')),
    array(
        'data'=>'js:jQuery(this).parents("form").serialize()+ "&request=added"',
        'success'=>'function(data){
$("#ChartArea").html(data);
}'
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>'ajaxSubmitBtn',
        'name'=>'ajaxSubmitBtn',
        'class'=>'btn btn-primary'
    ));
$this->endWidget();
```

In the controller: actionChart() method:

```
public function actionChart()
{
    if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    {
        $chartName=$_POST["chartName"];
        if($chartName=="callTrend")
        {
            $data = array('from_date'=>$_POST["from_date"],'to_date'
            =>$_POST["to_date"],'project_id'=>$_POST["project"]);
            $cchart="mychart";
        }
        elseif($chartName=="topProducts"){
            $data = array('from_date'=>$_POST["from_date1"],'to_date'=>$_POST["to_date1"]);
            $cchart="mychart1";
        }
        elseif($chartName=="topCallers"){
            $data = array('project_id'=>$_POST["project1"]);
            $cchart="mychart2";
        }
        $chartType=$_POST["chartType"];
    }
    else
    {
        $data=array();
        $chartName="callTrend";
        $cchart="mychart";
        $chartType="Line";
    }
    $this->renderPartial('_chart',array('cchart'=>$cchart,'chartName' =>$chartName,
            'chartType'=>$chartType,'data'=>$data));
}
```

In my controller: actionCallTrend method:

```
public function actionCallTrend($from_date=NULL,$to_date=NULL,$project_id=NULL)
{
    echo Yii::trace(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($from_date),'vardump');
    echo Yii::trace(CVarDumper::dumpAsString($to_date),'vardump');
    Yii::app()->fusioncharts->setChartOptions( array( 'caption'=>'Last Week Call Trend',
            'xAxisName'=>'Date', 'yAxisName'=>'Calls' ) );
    $con="";
    if($from_date!=NULL && $to_date==NULL)
    {
        $con="DATE(answer_ts) >= '$from_date'";  // date is database date column field
    }elseif($to_date!=NULL && $from_date==NULL)
    {
        $con="DATE(answer_ts) <= '$to_date'";
    }elseif($from_date!=NULL and $to_date!=NULL){
        $con="DATE(answer_ts)  >= '$from_date' and DATE(answer_ts) <= '$to_date'";
    }
    if(($from_date!=NULL or $to_date!=NULL) && $project_id!=NULL)
    {
        $con.=" and project_id = '$project_id'";  // date is database date column field
    }
    $stats=Creport::model()->findAll(array(
            'select'=>'COUNT(id) as data_count, DATE(answer_ts) as unique_date, answer_ts',
            'condition'=>$con,
            'group'=>'DATE(answer_ts)',
            'order'=>'answer_ts desc',
            'limit'=>10,
        ));
    $ddg=Yii::app()->dateFormatter;
    foreach ($stats as $s){
        Yii::app()->fusioncharts->addSet(array('label'=>$ddg->format("dd",$s->answer_ts)."-"
                .$ddg->format("MMM",$s->answer_ts), 'value'=>$s->data_count));
    }
    Yii::app()->fusioncharts->useI18N = true;
    Yii::app()->fusioncharts->addTrendLine(array('startValue'=>'700000',
            'color'=>'009933', 'displayvalue'=>'Target'));
    Yii::app()->fusioncharts->addDefinition(array('name'=>'CanvasAnim',
            'type'=>'animation', 'param'=>'_xScale', 'start'=>'0', 'duration'=>'1'));
    Yii::app()->fusioncharts->addApplication(array('toObject'=>'Canvas',
            'styles'=>'CanvasAnim'));
    Yii::app()->fusioncharts->getXMLData();
}
```

This is my code. it works without ajax but when i filtering the fields using ajax the same output will be displayed, they will not get the from_date, to_date & project_id in the actionCallTrend controller.

Answer (score 0):

to get access to variables in :

`public function actionCallTrend($from_date=NULL,$to_date=NULL,$project_id=NULL)`

you need to have those mapped in your url manager,

it is better to write:

```
public function actionCallTrend() {
     $from_date  = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('from_date ', null);
     $to_date    = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('to_date', null);
     $project_id = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('project_id', null);
```

you could also use the `Yii::app()->request->getParam()` if you're unsure about POST or GET